# How to sell digital goods in a PhoneGap/Cordova application on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, payment-gateway, payment

I am porting my (Cordova) app from BlackBerry10 to Android and have not been able to find the equivalent of the following plugins:

```
blackberry.payment.getPrice(options);
blackberry.payment.getExistingPurchases();
blackberry.payment.purchase({ digitalGoodSKU: '12345' });
```

Has anyone written a plugin that can be used to enable in-app payments from within a PhoneGap/Cordova application, that integrates with the Android Marketplace?

Hoping for something that provides a great user experience. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A developer has created a Cordova plugin for In-app billing on Android:

https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/README.md

Answer (score 0):

there is also a plugin for iOS: https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS
which has separated support for Crodova >3 and 2.9<